# Reverse the order of an index of numbers in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, array-reverse

my script :

```
$reverse_sets = array_reverse($sets);
foreach ($extraset as $element) {
    foreach ($sets as $index => $set) {
        if (in_array($element, $set)) {
            $actual_index = count($sets)-$index-1;
            echo "Extraset element '$element' is in set $actual_index<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

outputs me an $actual_index serie of numbers, from 20 to 0.

I need  to **reverse** the output of $actual_index displaying the numbers backwards (from 0 to 20), without touching the previous logic of the script.

**I tried using again array reverse on $actual_index, creating $final_index :**

```
$reverse_sets = array_reverse($sets);
foreach ($extraset as $element) {
    foreach ($sets as $index => $set) {
        if (in_array($element, $set)) {
            $actual_index = count($sets)-$index-1;
            $final_index = array_reverse($actual_index);
            echo "Extraset element '$element' is in set $final_index<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but i don't get any output.

What is wrong with my code ? How do I fix this ?  thanks for your help

Comment: You can use php function array_reverse to reverse your final array.

Comment: As you can see in my try, i used array_reverse on $actual_index , creating a $final_index, but i get no output